# Finding qt4 libraries for arm-Linux

Tags: qt, makefile

Using FindQt.cmake for finding QT libraries:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL )
```

However, I always receive this warning:

```
The ASM compiler identification is GNU

CMake Warning at ../cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:601 (MESSAGE):
  /Qt4.8.0/bin/qmake reported
  QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/Qt4.8.0/lib"
  but QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
```

I am sure there is QtCore libraries under: /Qt4.8.0/lib

```
ls -all libQtCore*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     950 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     942 Nov 30 13:07 libQtCore.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Nov 30 13:07 libQtCore.so -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4.8 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2697932 Nov 30 13:08 libQtCore.so.4.8.0
```

How can I check why there is such a warning that QtCore could not be found in that directory?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the code of `FindQt4.cmake` module from `CMake` distribution I've founfd workaround for this issue. I've set `QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE` in addition to `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` variable. I put them into my `cmake` toolchain in the following way:

```
# Qt4 related stuff required here due to FindQt4.cmake issues
set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE $ENV{QT_DIR}/bin/qmake)
set(QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE $ENV{QT_DIR}/lib/libQtCore.so)
```

I use `QT_DIR` environment variable in order to simplify switching between different Qt4 builds.